# How to calculate area of a multipolygon layer using qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator?

Tags: python, qgis

I am trying to include a calculated field in a layer called say "test.shp"
I have added it as a vector layer in my QGIS
I want to calculate area of each polygon in that layer. I am writing the following code:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator",test,"Area",1,10,10,value=geom.area(),"...address/test2.shp")
```

Its showing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar using the `qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns` algorithm.

This will add perimeter and area columns to your layer.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot.